# Get the path of a directory in HTA

Tags: html, directory, jscript, hta, webkitdirectory

I want the user to provide the path of a folder or directory via an input tag that is created as below:

```js
var newinput = document.createElement('input');
newinput.type = "file";
newinput.webkitdirectory; ///I am using IE for hta so I am not sure if this will work
document.body.appendChild(newinput);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know if webkitdirectory works with hta and if I can add it to the input after creating a new element. (I only want to get the path of a certain directory, not files in the directory)

Comment: who uses an 11 year old browser - [caniuse says no](https://caniuse.com/?search=webkitdirectory)

Comment: I want to make an hta, not a webpage in the browser.

Comment: Oh ... so, [caniuse STILL says no](https://caniuse.com/?search=webkitdirectory)

Comment: _"I want to know if webkitdirectory works with hta"_ - and what exactly is stopping you from simply _testing_ it then?

Comment: I tested it in the above snippet, but if I try to select a folder it shows "open" and not select. So it is not accepting folders, only files.

Comment: So If I cannot use webkitdirectory in IE(hta), is there another way to select dirs and not files in hta?

Comment: I only want to get the path of the selected directory, not files in the directory

Comment: Since you attempted to use code in an HTA that can't possibly work, it seems you're not clear on the basics. HTAs are rendered by Microsoft's MSHTML, which  is the same engine used by IE. Therefore, you are limited to what's possible in IE 11. Also note that without any declarations, your HTA will run in IE 5 mode. With an html doctype, it will default to IE 7 mode. You'll need to add the correct declaration to run in higher modes (up to IE 11). And be aware that the "Edge" mode has nothing to do with the Edge browser. It just means run in the highest mode available which is IE 11.

Comment: I know what hta is and how it runs, but as IE does not support webkitdirectory, I had to use another procedure:

function selectFolder() {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder:", 0, 0);
  if (folder) {
    var folderPath = folder.Self.Path;
    ///Use folderPath var here
  }
}

Comment: Yes, we see that you found the correct solution, but if you fully understood, you wouldn't have tried webkitdirectory or asked about it. The question should have simply been "how to implement a folder picker in an HTA".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you who tried to help, I found the following solution:

```
function selectFolder() {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
  var folder = shell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a folder:", 0, 0);
  if (folder) {
    var folderPath = folder.Self.Path;
    ///Use folderPath var here
  }
}
```